# can the same node in python be a publisher and a subscriber?

Tags: ros, node, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do a node that reads the position of a joint and then publish tourqe.
Or maybe can it be 2 nodes in the same code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49311/can-the-same-node-in-python-be-a-publisher-and-a-subscriber?/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. One node can do both. Why not?

You can call publish() from a subscriber callback.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4